# Weird issue with UIWindow on iPad mini in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, orientation, uiwindow

I have created a custom toast message and adding this message to a custom `UIWindow` (since I want this message on top of everything).
My custom toast message is nothing but a subclass of `UIViewController` and `UIView` of this `UIViewController` I have added a `UILabel` which is the toast message.

As far as the custom `UIWindow` is concern I took this class from `JLToast` as it is and this is how it look like…

```
public class JLToastWindow: UIWindow {

    public static let sharedWindow = JLToastWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    /// Will not return `rootViewController` while this value is `true`. Or the rotation will be fucked in iOS 9.
    var isStatusBarOrientationChanging = false

    var shouldRotateManually: Bool {
        let iPad = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad
        let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        let window = application.delegate?.window ?? nil
        let supportsAllOrientations = application.supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow(window) == .All

        let info = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary
        let requiresFullScreen = info?["UIRequiresFullScreen"]?.boolValue == true
        let hasLaunchStoryboard = info?["UILaunchStoryboardName"] != nil

        if #available(iOS 9, *), iPad && supportsAllOrientations && !requiresFullScreen && hasLaunchStoryboard {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    override public var rootViewController: UIViewController? {
        get {
            guard !self.isStatusBarOrientationChanging else { return nil }
            return UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first?.rootViewController
        }
        set { /* Do nothing */ }
    }

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.userInteractionEnabled = false
        self.windowLevel = CGFloat.max
        self.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
        self.hidden = false
        self.handleRotate(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: #selector(self.bringWindowToTop),
            name: UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification,
            object: nil
        )
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: #selector(self.statusBarOrientationWillChange),
            name: UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification,
            object: nil
        )
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: #selector(self.statusBarOrientationDidChange),
            name: UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification,
            object: nil
        )
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: #selector(self.applicationDidBecomeActive),
            name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,
            object: nil
        )
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    /// Bring JLToastWindow to top when another window is being shown.
    func bringWindowToTop(notification: NSNotification) {
        if !(notification.object is JLToastWindow) {
            self.dynamicType.sharedWindow.hidden = true
            self.dynamicType.sharedWindow.hidden = false
        }
    }

    dynamic func statusBarOrientationWillChange() {
        self.isStatusBarOrientationChanging = true
    }

    dynamic func statusBarOrientationDidChange() {
        let orientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation
        self.handleRotate(orientation)
        self.isStatusBarOrientationChanging = false
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
        let orientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation
        self.handleRotate(orientation)
    }

    func handleRotate(orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        let angle = self.angleForOrientation(orientation)
        if self.shouldRotateManually {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(angle))
        }

        if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first {
            if orientation.isPortrait || !self.shouldRotateManually {
                self.frame.size.width = window.bounds.size.width
                self.frame.size.height = window.bounds.size.height
            } else {
                self.frame.size.width = window.bounds.size.height
                self.frame.size.height = window.bounds.size.width
            }
        }

        self.frame.origin = .zero

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            JLToastCenter.defaultCenter().currentToast?.view.updateView()
        }
    }

    func angleForOrientation(orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) -> Double {
        switch orientation {
        case .LandscapeLeft: return -M_PI_2
        case .LandscapeRight: return M_PI_2
        case .PortraitUpsideDown: return M_PI
        default: return 0
        }
    }

}
```

I know, there were some implementation change for `UIWindow` in **iOS 8**, so if I add some view to `UIWindow` (which is I’m doing , adding toast message view to above custom `UIWindow`) then that `UIView/UIWindow` will not receive any rotation change. this problem is handle by above window thanks to JLToast buddy.
My toast message is working fine in almost all device, but problem is with **iPad mini 9.3.1 and iPad 3 8.3**(in rest devices and versions, this works fine) **UIWindow/UIView** not rotating when start app with `Landscape` or move device to `Landscape`. ***Interestingly toast being display fine on iPad mini 9.2 but not on iPad mini 9.3.1***.

Any one can provide some pointer for this issue.

**EDIT:**  please find demo [Code Here](https://github.com/suryakants/ToastTest.git) 
As I already mention this issue can be found on iPad Mini iOS 9.3.1 (Non-Retina) and iPad 3  iOS8.3, as per what I found.